# Using Like Within Case Structure

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement

I have a case structure the decodes a string value and actions code based on the value.  The case structure is pretty straight forward where it decodes predefined values (e.g. "/Start", "/Run", etc).  However, I have one part of this case structure where I need to decode a changing value.

So for example, I need to capture the string value of "/IP:blah" (where blah will always change) and execute code based on blah.

My code would look something like this:

```
Select Case Message
Case Like "/SetServerIP:*"
                        'Determine IP from Message string (*)
                        'Set new IP address of server in my.settings
End Select
```

Not sure how this can be achieved.
Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Case` statement with the `Is` keyword and a comparison operator expression.

[Select...Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Use the Is keyword with a comparison operator (=, <>, <, <=, >, or >=) to specify a restriction on the match values for testexpression. If the Is keyword is not supplied, it is automatically inserted before comparisonoperator.

If the Case statement is valid you can then use `Substring()` to get the IP address like:

```
Dim IPAddress As String=String.Empty
Select Case Message

    Case "/Start"
        ' Your code here
    Case Is >= "/SetServerIP:"
        IPAddress = Message.Substring(13)
        ' your code here
End Select
```

this will e.g match
"/SetServerIP:127.0.0.1" => IPAddress = "127.0.0.1"
"/SetServerIP:" => IPAddress = ""

EDIT: Please note this will only work if you don't have a message which is in a String comparison `greater` than `/SetServerIP:` which would be true for e.g `/SftServerIP:` or `/SetServerIR`.

Comment: Worked a treat!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement to the already accepted answer.
Use the code below, worked for me

```
Select Case True 
Case Message Like "/SetServerIP:*"
                        'Determine IP from Message string (*)
                        'Set new IP address of server in my.settings
End Select
```

Comment: Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question. Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.

Answer (score 1):

In general with comparisons you would use `Is`:

```
Select Case aNumber
    Case Is > 42
End Select
```

… unfortunately, this doesn’t work with the `Like` operator (thanks to Heslacher for pointing this out to me). So this use-case isn’t supported by VB’s `Select Case` statement. You can use chained `If` statements instead.

Alternatively, *first* parse out the command from your message and select based on that:

```
Dim command = Message.Split(":"c)(0)

Select Case command
    Case "/SetServerIP"
    …
End Select
```

Comment: This won't work, as the Is keyword expects an comparison operator expression like <,>,>= [SelectCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Heslacher I don’t have VS so I cannot confirm but according to the documentation, `Is` is followed by a “comparison operator” and [`Like` is a comparison operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx). If you have Visual Studio, could you verify this for me? If it doesn’t work, is that an inaccuracy in the documentation or a compiler bug?

Comment: @Heslacher Ah, I checked the VB 10 specification, and §10.8.2 (“Select Case Statements”) *redefines* the “comparison operator” rule to exclude `Like`. How odd.

Comment: I did check this before i have posted that comment. In VB 2010 it shows as an error ( in a Select..Case )